# Wamp PHPMyAdmin Fatal error: Call to a member function getName() on a non-object

Tags: phpmyadmin, fatal-error

I use `MySQL` within `WAMP` without any problem.

I just have a problem with `PHPMyAdmin` access.

I get a message:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getName() on a non-object in
C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin4.0.4\libraries\common.inc.php on line 718
```

and

```
require_once( 'C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin4.0.4\libraries\common.inc.php' )
```

Versions

```
Wamp server version is 2.4
Apache version is 2.4.4
PHP version 5.4.12
MySQL version 5.6.12
```

I do not have a problem with `LocalHost` menu
or with my apps.

```
Hosts file is:
127.0.0.1   localhost
::1             localhost
```

**How can I fix that problem???**

Comment: Which action are you doing to see this message?

Comment: did you create your config.inc.php file?

Answer (score 0):

the problem comes from intl extention

disable it